# English compound

Tags: grammar

Is there a grammatical rule to compound a set of words such as a single one? *e.g.* 
word1 word2 --> word1word2  or word1-word2? Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rule I read related to evolution of compound words.

Most compound words start out as two words :

Air plane, Space ship

Stage two, they are hyphenated :

Air-plane, Space-ship

Stage three, over time they start become accepted as a single word:

Airplane,Spaceship

I am not whether this answers your question, but hope it helps.

Comment: It's OK, but I was wondering too, if it is possible to know numeric details about those stages of compounding such as the specific time of acceptance; additionaly, what/who lets that new way of writing? At the end of the day, what does it determine which one of that triad of "words" is the correct in a specific sentence?